# Custom Attribute not having a bindable property bound

Tags: aurelia

Maybe someone can help me with this.

I cannot seem to bind a callback to a customAttribute.
Here goes some code

```
import {inject, customAttribute, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'typeahead';

@customAttribute('typeahead')
@inject(Element)
export class Typeahead {
    @bindable minLength = 0;
    @bindable highlight = true;
    @bindable substringMatcher = null;

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        var self = this;
        $(self.element).typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: self.highlight,
            minLength: self.minLength
        },
        {
            name: 'query',
            source: (query) =>
            {
                console.log(self.substringMatcher);
                if(self.substringMatcher){
                    self.substringMatcher(query);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I've been trying to assign the substringMatcher bindable callback in several ways but the property is always null

```
<input typeahead="substringMatcher.bind: search" class="form-control typeahead">
<input typeahead="substringMatcher: search" class="form-control typeahead">
<input typeahead="substringMatcher: this.search" class="form-control typeahead">
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong case on the attributes...

This worked:
`<input typeahead="substring-matcher: search" class="form-control typeahead">`